# VueJs & Laravel. I can't send an excel file with Vuejs and FileReader

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to load an excel file to send it with axios to Controller and Maatwebsite\Excel for an Import.

The import part in Controller is working when i use Php from blade, i have a problem when sending from  my Vuejs Component. I can't Read the Excel File. or Maybe i can't read it in Controller.

This is my code :

```
<template>
  <input type="file"  @change="checkFile" />
  <button @click="importExcel()">Import File</button>
</template>

<script>
//In method 
  checkFile(e) {
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log('#', files); // The file is in console
    if (!files.length)
    return;
    this.createFile(files[0]);
  },

createFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var vm = this;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  vm.ex.excel=file; // my ex.excel object contain File
 },

importExcel: function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.ex.excel);
    axios.post('/importExcel', formData)
          },  

</script>
```

So in Controller, i use this code when i'm using php (working)

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
       Excel::import(new UsersImport, request()->file('import_file'));
    }
    return back();
}
```

When i try this code for axios. i have an error :

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->excel);
    return back();
}
```

Error: **No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected**

Console.log(file) in image[image]

UPDATE: In controller i added

```
$a = $request->excel;
dd($a);
result in : null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<template>
  <input type="file" ref="file"  @change="checkFile" />
  <button @click="importExcel()">Import File</button>
</template>

<script>
//In method 
{
  ...

  createFile(file) {
    this.ex.excel = this.$refs.file.target.value.files[0]
  }
  ...
  }
</script>
```

```html
<?php

...
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file('file'));
    return back();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the mime-type is missing, try add the mime-type together with your HTTP POST ...

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I don't know how to do that. Any explications please ?